# Testing IE 10 in Microsoft remote desktop on mac?

Tags: macos, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10, remote-desktop, browser-testing

I'm using Microsoft Remote Desktop App on my Mac which is connected to my microsoft account in order to test for "IE Technical Preview" which is IE11.

Is it possible to test for IE10 with this App as well?

Kind Regards,
Matt

Comment: What prevents you from connecting to a machine with IE10 installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem so.  However, you should be able to [select and download a virtual machine](https://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads) image from modern.ie.

The UI of the site dynamically adapts to your OS, so use it to get a sense of what's available to you.  (The [release notes](http://modernievirt.blob.core.windows.net/vhd/release_notes_license_terms_1_5_15.pdf) refer to VMWare Fusion, VirtualBox, and Parallels.  Hopefully, one of those is available to you.)

Hope this helps...

-- Lance

Answer (score 1):

I like this solution

https://github.com/xdissent/ievms

With one command it brings to your computer ready-to-use virtual machines with different versions of IE. Very useful for me.